# w3css - Making divs inside column divs have equal height

Tags: css, html

In a html5 game i am making i have created an upgrades store. I am trying to get the upgrades in each column to have the same height but they are displaying with different heights when one of the paragraphs is too long for one line. which is making the rows in the columns different sizes.

[here is an image of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heYZ0.png)

I want them to be the same size but nothing I have tried is working. Here is the code snippet and the jsfiddle.

```html
<link href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="w3-row w3-border w3-border-black code-blocks-upgrades" style="display: flex; width: 1111px; margin: 0; padding: 0">
  <div class="w3-col l6 m6 s6" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex: 1">
    <div class="w3-row w3-center w3-border-top w3-border-left w3-border-right w3-border-black w3-padding-small" style="display: flex; align-items: center; flex: 1">
      <div class="w3-col l5 m5 s5" style="display: table; height: 26px">
        <p id="buy-code-blocks-speed-label" class="w3-small" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle">Buy Code Blocks Speed ($1000.00): </p>
      </div>
      <div class="w3-col l7 m7 s7 w3-left-align" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row">
        <button class="w3-btn w3-yellow w3-small w3-padding-small" onclick="">1</button>
        <button class="w3-btn w3-orange w3-small w3-padding-small" onclick="">10</button>
        <button class="w3-btn w3-red w3-small w3-padding-small" onclick="">100</button>
        <button class="w3-btn w3-black w3-small w3-padding-small" onclick="">Max</button>
        <input class="w3-small w3-border w3-border-black" style="height: 26px; width: 50px; flex: 1" type="text" placeholder="Custom" onkeypress="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-row w3-center w3-border w3-border-black w3-padding-small" style="display: flex; align-items: center; flex: 1">
      <div class="w3-col l5 m5 s5" style="display: table; height: 26px">
        <p id="buy-code-blocks-strength-label" class="w3-small" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle">Buy Code Blocks Strength ($1000.00): </p>
      </div>
      <div class="w3-col l7 m7 s7 w3-left-align" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row">
        <button class="w3-btn w3-yellow w3-small w3-padding-small" onclick="">1</button>
        <button class="w3-btn w3-orange w3-small w3-padding-small" onclick="">10</button>
        <button class="w3-btn w3-red w3-small w3-padding-small" onclick="">100</button>
        <button class="w3-btn w3-black w3-small w3-padding-small" onclick="">Max</button>
        <input class="w3-small w3-border w3-border-black" style="height: 26px; width: 50px; flex: 1" type="text" placeholder="Custom" onkeypress="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-col l6 m6 s6" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex: 1">
    <div class="w3-row w3-center w3-border-top w3-border-right w3-border-black w3-padding-small" style="display: flex; align-items: center; flex: 1">
      <div class="w3-col l5 m5 s5" style="display: table; height: 26px">
        <p id="sell-code-blocks-speed-label" class="w3-small" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle">Sell Code Blocks Speed ($100.00): </p>
      </div>
      <div class="w3-col l7 m7 s7 w3-left-align" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row">
        <button class="w3-btn w3-yellow w3-small w3-padding-small" onclick="">1</button>
        <button class="w3-btn w3-orange w3-small w3-padding-small" onclick="">10</button>
        <button class="w3-btn w3-red w3-small w3-padding-small" onclick="">100</button>
        <button class="w3-btn w3-black w3-small w3-padding-small" onclick="">Max</button>
        <input class="w3-small w3-border w3-border-black" style="height: 26px; width: 50px; flex: 1" type="text" placeholder="Custom" onkeypress="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-row w3-center w3-border-top w3-border-bottom w3-border-right w3-border-black w3-padding-small" style="display: flex; align-items: center; flex: 1">
      <div class="w3-col l5 m5 s5" style="display: table; height: 26px">
        <p id="sell-code-blocks-strength-label" class="w3-small" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle">Sell Code Blocks Strength ($100.00): </p>
      </div>
      <div class="w3-col l7 m7 s7 w3-left-align" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row">
        <button class="w3-btn w3-yellow w3-small w3-padding-small" onclick="game.convert_amount(event, 1, 'code_blocks_strength');">1</button>
        <button class="w3-btn w3-orange w3-small w3-padding-small" onclick="game.convert_amount(event, 10, 'code_blocks_strength');">10</button>
        <button class="w3-btn w3-red w3-small w3-padding-small" onclick="game.convert_amount(event, 100, 'code_blocks_strength');">100</button>
        <button class="w3-btn w3-black w3-small w3-padding-small" onclick="game.convert_amount(event, 'max', 'code_blocks_strength');">Max</button>
        <input class="w3-small w3-border w3-border-black" style="height: 26px; width: 50px; flex: 1" type="text" placeholder="Custom" onkeypress="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here is the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joshgil4/yvnwt1ty/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here is the result in fiddle and the code snippet you add here... There doesn't seem to be a problem as the one in the picture you attached..

Comment: If I run it in chrome the buy code blocks strength paragraph takes up two columns but the sell code blocks strength paragraph takes up one. I want to make it so that at least the middle horizontal borders are connected or even better make the other upgrades have the same size as the ones with two line paragraphs.